# Passing list to string formatter in Python

Tags: python, loops, parameter-passing, string-formatting

I am making a Python script to turn a CSV into a GeoJSON file, however, I want to use it over again with different datasets, and don't want to hard code anything. I am trying to pass a list of items to a string formatter within a loop. I keep getting errors and saw that Python can take a list as an argument in a function and iterate through it separately, but it doesn't seem to be able to do that with  string formatters.

How can I pass an unknown amount of arguments to a string formatter within a loop?

```
iter = 0
for row in rows:
  iter += 1
  if iter >= 2:
    latitude = lat_long_location["latitude"]
    longitude = lat_long_location["longitude"]
    property_arr = [row[longitude], row[latitude]]
    item_index = 0
    for ind, item in enumerate(row):
      if ind is latitude or ind is longitude:
        print("next")
      else:
        property_arr.append(item)
    #output += template.format(*property_arr) 
    output += template % (*property_arr)
```

Comment: What is `next` supposed to be doing? Also using  `is latitude`  and `is longitude` are bad ideas. `is` checks  the identity of an object

Comment: oops, I meant print("next"). Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @NicholasGati: The commented out code: `template.format(*property_arr)` should have worked for you (provided the template is appropriate).

Comment: When I tried that it gave me an error, which I thought was weird since I researched a bit and it seemed like it would work. I ended up changing it to: `output += template % tuple(property_arr)` as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams recommended and it worked. I'll look into changing the is latitude and is longitude. Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasGati,  your code has a serious problem that should have been addressed, run `a = 12345;b=12345;a is b` from a shell

Answer (score 0):

That's not how positional expansion works. But it's the wrong tool anyways.

```
output += template % tuple(property_arr)
```

Comment: It works! I am fairly new to Python, so I didn't know about this and it stumped me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Converting the sequence of format targets to a tuple.